# What exactly does M/monit mean?

Tags: monitoring, monit

what exactly does M/monit mean?

Answer (score 7):

Monit by itself is a standalone software monitoring application.  For example, it can restart Apache if it stops responding.

M/Monit is a somewhat centralized control panel.  You still use Monit on the individual servers, but you get an extra control panel/GUI with it.

Monit is free, M/Monit is not.

Comment: And for total peace of mind use Monit with Munin and all your server reporting tools are complete!

Comment: ok, is it possible to configure mmonit web interface and access the monit services to it

Comment: how exactly mmonit web interface can be installed?

Comment: It's a commercial product, I'm sure if you were to purchase it they would be able to help you.  I've never used it, so I really can't say.

Answer (score 1):

I always assumed it stands for "multiple Monit" but I couldn't find anything to support that assumption on their website or manuals.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @ewwhite -> I don't question your statement, nor the Nic's, it really makes sense but, do you have some source for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the etymology of M/Monit, one of my colleagues noted that the name sounds like "I'm not it.".